# Hibernate with MSSQL server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am very new to hibernate.I created simple application with `hibernate` connecting with `MSSQL server 2008`.While executing the program I got the `Exception`.Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at com.main.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:15)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection refused: connect Nested exception: Connection refused: connect
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 2 more
```

my conf file.

*employee.hbm.xml*

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

 <hibernate-mapping>  
  <class name="com.pojo.Employee" table="employee">  
    <id name="id">  
     <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
    </id>  
    <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"></property>  
    <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"></property>         
  </class>           
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Hibernate config file

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
              "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
              "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  

    <hibernate-configuration>         
        <session-factory>         
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>  
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=sampleDB</property>  
            <property name="connection.username">sa</property>  
            <property name="connection.password">sa123</property>  
            <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>              
        <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>  
        </session-factory>  
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: you should check for typo's before you post the question

Answer (score 1):

You have to close all open tags, like this one:

```
<property name="connection.password"sa123</property>
```

Should be changed to:

```
<property name="connection.password">sa123</property>
```

Comment: i changed and now also i got the same exception..please help me to resolve this...thanks n advance..

Comment: Could you please try to add "hibernate." prefix to all properties? I haven't looked at hibernate code to check if it is required but I have them all prefixed and it works.

Comment: If you will go there [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/523943/ORM/databases/parse-hibernate-cfg-xml) you will find out that this might be related to DTD loading issue. Try to substitute DTD with a local one.